# C# open page in new tab

Tags: c#, webforms

I have this code:

```
string urlAccomodation = ar.GetAccommodationHashURL(
    StudentId.ToString(),
    sp.GetSysSetting("accomodationSecret"),
    misc.GetAppSetting("urlAccommodation"));
string returnURL = "&url=" + Server.UrlEncode(
    ar.GetHashURL(
        StudentId.ToString(),
        sp.GetSysSetting("accomodationSecret"),
        "http://applicants.rac.ac.uk/default.aspx"));
string url = "window.open('" + urlAccomodation + returnURL + "_blank')";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Script", url, true);
```

What I'm trying to do is open a page in a new tab. It works fine for Mozilla and Internet Explorer but Chrome and Safari are opening this in a new window instead of a new tab.
Can you please help ?
(I do apologize for my English)

Comment: Please edit your question so that the code is properly formatted.

Comment: It is up to the browser how to open a page. You can change the browser's settings manually though.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure based in the info provided, and might not help anyway, but you might be mis-formatting the `string url=` line:

```
string url = "window.open('" + urlAccomodation + returnURL + "_blank')";
```

Try

```
string url = "window.open('" + urlAccomodation + returnURL + "','_blank')";
```

The target should be a separate argument to the `window.open` method, eg: `window.open('some.aspx','_blank')`

Answer (score 0):

From what I know this is browser setting and cannot be controlled from code.

I'm guessing it works on FF and IE because of the proper settings in place.